# ArcMap: Identify mismatch between position of points from database with their actual location in polygons

Tags: arcmap, sql, point-in-polygon

A map in ArcMap contains two datasets:

1. Points `J_i` from table `Jurisdiction` of an SQL-database (SQL Server 2017) displayed by `Display XY Data` (*Data Type: XY Event Source*)
2. Polygon shapefile feature `Districts` with polygons for districts

The table `Jurisdiction` contains column `District` which tells within which district polygon a specific point `J_i` is expected to be located. How can I identify points `J_i`, which are not located within the district polygon as suggested by column `District`? A goal would be to make those points visible.

Adding a field with field calculation in table `Jurisdiction` ist not applicable as `Jurisdiction` has a database connection. Other approaches I know from the toolbox produce static results. The approach should dynamically react to modified entries in `Jurisdiction` as `Jurisdiction` experiences ongoing editing.

[image: Only show points with mismatch.]

Comment: Your problem statement is quite terse; using descriptive names (more than one character) and a diagram or three might make your process clearer. I doubt you can detect remote activity in a passive map application. A proper Query Layer might be of more use than a cached event layer.

Comment: Spatial Join would allow you to select features where they belong.  This could of course be done completely within SQL, if the database supports spatial queries (you could even have a trigger to correct the encoding and add a log record on insert).

Comment: @Vince: please give your answer as a full answer instead of a comment so I can mark it as an accepted answer. I was successful by integrating both point and polygon features as point and polygon geometries into SQL, creating a View combined with a Scalar-valued-Function and by displaying the View in any GIS-application.

Comment: Sorry, too busy with COVID-19 support to fashion a proper answer. Feel free to self-answer, though the question doesn't mention which database (to make it answerable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer as derived from `Vince`'s suggestion:

1. In database, create tables `Jurisdiction` and `District` with columns `J_POINT` of
   *Point Geometry Data Type* (`geometry::Point`) and `D_POLYGON` of *Polygon Geometry Data Type* (`geometry::Polygon`) respectively [see image]
2. Create `View Mismatch` with condition:

```
SELECT J.J_POINT
FROM dbo.Jurisdiction AS J INNER JOIN
dbo.District AS D ON J.J_POINT.STWithin(D.D_POLYGON) = 1 AND J.J_DISTRICT <> D.D_NAME
```

3. Plot result from `View Mismatch` in GIS

[image]